# Rails 4.2 self-join model -- Create method returns error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a simple self-join model for an Account. An Account can have a single parent and/or multiple child Accounts.

Here is the class:

```
class Account < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :children, class_name: "Account", foreign_key: "parent_id"
  belongs_to :parent, class_name: "Account"
end
```

and the migration:

```
class CreateAccounts < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :accounts do |t|
      t.references :parent, index: true
      t.string :name
      t.string :category
      t.timestamps null: false
    end
  end
end
```

When the create method is invoked on the controller, I get the following error:

```
Account(#70188397277860) expected, got String(#70188381177720)
```

and it references the first line of the create method in the controller:

```
def create
  @account = Account.new(account_params)

  respond_to do |format|
    if @account.save
      format.html { redirect_to @account, notice: 'Account was successfully created.' }
      format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @account }
    else
      format.html { render :new }
      format.json { render json: @account.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end
```

Since the Account model is self-referential, it seems like Rails expects an Account as an argument for constructing an Account.

The Rails ActiveRecord Guide has a limited example which I believe I have followed closely, but I cannot figure out where I am going wrong.

I have tried various permutations foreign key types and what-not with no luck. Any pointers are appreciated.

EDIT:

Here is the form, generated by the scaffold command, that gathers the information for creating a new account. As suggested by @SteveTurczyn in the comments, the form is collecting a string for the parent field instead of an id.

```
<%= form_for(@account) do |f| %>
  <% if @account.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(@account.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this account from being saved\
:</h2>

      <ul>
      <% @account.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
        <li><%= message %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :parent %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :parent %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :name %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :name %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :category %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :category %>
  </div>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

EDIT2:

Changing the `parent` field from `text_field` to `number_field` has no effect on the result.

The parameters passed to the create method are the same:

```
{"utf8"=>"✓",
"authenticity_token"=>"pq0sp162cA7Bmn7uw67F7gOvUVLj/S+xcasVibqysiF68vheVkATsf4pwKgPqH5nawjc0BnIj3qoot8JyIeVmg==",
 "account"=>{"parent"=>"0",
 "name"=>"Foo",
 "category"=>"Bar"},
 "commit"=>"Create Account"}
```

I'm a little confused about how this is supposed to work.

Comment: Be useful to see the view... it looks like the account_params is passing a string into the attribute "parent" which is why you have the problem.  Are you selecting a parent when you select the record?  Perhaps you should select `parent_id` on the form... returning an ID would likely fix the problem.

Comment: @SteveTurczyn I'm using the form generated by the scaffold command for creating new accounts. I will post the code when I get back to my computer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're submitting the ID of a `parent` from the form, but your association expects `parent` to actually be an Account object, not the ID of one.

Change the form to submit `parent_id` instead of `parent`.

Comment: When I change the form to submit `parent_id`, the Account object is successfully created but the parent_id field in the database is always `null`.

Comment: Is your `account_params` method also permitting `parent_id` instead of `parent`?